# Unable to mount windows partition to ubuntu livecd

Tags: mount, windows

My windows installation has crapped, probably because of a faulty hdd. Looking to backup the files but have trouble accessing the.

fdisk gives me the following:

[image: fdisk]

I've tried mounting with `sudo mount /dev/sdb5 -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb /media/pendrive`

Nothing appears in /media/pendrive

Any help?

Comment: In the future, rather than post an image, it would be better to copy/paste the output from the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mount each device partition in different mountpoints i.e:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb5 /mnt

sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/pendrive
```

Check what device is your USB, it can't be the same as your disk (`/dev/sdb`), it shoud be for example `/dev/sdc`.

Note the **1** in `/dev/sdc1`, you have to mount the partition of the device.

Then you can access your windows files in the directory `/mnt`, and copy them to `/media/pendrive`.

Comment: Do i need to mount all the partition? The personal data is on sdb5

Comment: @p4CK4dzDZVjSjoukQrRl No, just the ones you are going to work with, the windows partition (/dev/sdb5) and the usb (probably /dev/sdc1).

Comment: @p4CK4dzDZVjSjoukQrRl Note that you have a windows /dev/sdb7 partition, what's in there? Maybe you have a data partition (like D:\).

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity maybe i'll have to mount both 5 & 7 and then add a usb hdd to copy the files later.

Comment: Mounted a usb hdd to copy the files onto and ...it's stuck on 'preparing to copy'. Let's see if it finishes anytime soon.